# Inequality on Alternating Sum of Fractions with Increasing Denominator

Tags: inequality

**Question**: Consider the following function involving an alternating sum over fractions, with increasing denominator:
$$f(x, y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n})=\sum\limits_{I\subseteq \{1, \ldots, n\}}(-1)^{|I|}\frac{1}{1+x+\sum\limits_{i\in I}y_{i}},$$
Either show the following inequality $$\forall x, y_1, \ldots, y_n>0\text{ , we have } f(x, y_1, \ldots, y_n)>0$$
or provide a counterexample where this does not hold.

**My Attempt**: I started first by working on small $n$. For $n=1$, this becomes $$f(x, y_1)=\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{1+x+y_1}>0.$$

For $n=2$, this becomes $$\begin{aligned}
f(x, y_1, y_2)&=\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{1+x+y_1}-\frac{1}{1+x+y_2}+\frac{1}{1+x+y_1+y_2}\\
&=\frac{(2+2x+y_1+y_2)}{(1+x)(1+x+y_1+y_2)}-\frac{(2+2x+y_1+y_2)}{(1+x+y_1)(1+x+y_2)}\\
&=\frac{(2+2x+y_1+y_2)y_1y_2}{(1+x)(1+x+y_1+y_2)(1+x+y_1)(1+x+y_2)}>0.
\end{aligned}$$

So it looks like the inequality holds, although it is difficult for me to generalize the above observations to general $n\geq 3$ (as number of terms grow exponentially). I also tried taking gradient of a particular variable, though that also leads to complicated expressions.

I would appreciate any help on this (or pointers to existing inequalities that solve the problem). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Find a recursion, i.e., express $f_n$ in terms of $f_{n-1}$ by splitting the subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ into those having $n$ as element and those that don’t.